# EWS: Accessing an appointments recurrence pattern

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the recurrence pattern associated with the appointment in the below code.  When I debug the code and expand the microsoftAppointment.Recurrence property in the Locals Window I can see a nested class called [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence.WeeklyPattern] that has the information in it I need but I can not figure out how to access this information in my code.  It is obviously in memory I just don't understand why I can't read it in code during run time.  I have tried FindAppointments but that only returns Recurrence as null.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(folderCount));

exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Location, AppointmentSchema.Body, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.IsAllDayEvent, AppointmentSchema.Body, AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring, AppointmentSchema.Recurrence));

foreach (var v in findResults.Items)
{
    Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment microsoftAppointment = v as Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment;

    if (microsoftAppointment.IsRecurring)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following casts ended up working for me.  You can skip the Interval Pattern step but I did a switch after that to find the type (weekly, daily, etc.) so I could correctly cast the interval pattern.

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence.IntervalPattern pattern = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence.IntervalPattern)microsoftAppointment.Recurrence;
weeklyPattern = (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Recurrence.WeeklyPattern) pattern;
```